# mule endpoint for calling C-program

Tags: esb, mule

i am new to mule and i need to invoke a **c-program** through a http connector.
unfortunately i was not able to find an **endpoint** that could help me invoke a C-program.
can someone tell if this is possible with mule? if so,how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by **c-program** you mean a program compiled to a native executable, I suggest you use an `expression-component` to invoke it via one of the `exec()` methods of `java.lang.Runtime`.